# How to redeliver messages to consumer, when it reconnects after sometimes in rabbitmq?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, rabbitmq, amqp

Initially only producer is connected and consumer( CTRL+C, intentional ) somehow fails to connect to RabbitMQ server, Meanwhile producer have sent 4 consecutive messages to exchange-topic/server, Will consumer get those messages when it connects again, In my case it is fail to get messages

**CODE BELOW ATTACHED CONSUMER PUBLISHER FILE**

**PRODUCER.JS**

```
const amqplib = require("amqplib");

const emitLogs = async () => {
const conn = await amqplib.connect("amqp://localhost");

const ch = await conn.createChannel();

let exchange = "direct_logs";
var args = process.argv.slice(2);
var msg = args.slice(1).join(" ") || "Hello World!";
var severity = args.length > 0 ? args[0] : "info";

await ch.assertExchange(exchange, "direct", {
    durable: true,
});

ch.publish(exchange, severity, Buffer.from(msg));

setTimeout(function () {
    conn.close();
    process.exit(0);
}, 500);
};
emitLogs();
```

**CONSUMER.JS**

```
 /* To simplify things we will assume that 'severity' can be one of 'info', 'warning', 
'error'. */
const amqplib = require("amqplib");

const receiveLogs = async () => {
try {
    var args = process.argv.slice(2);

    if (args.length == 0) {
        console.log(
            "Usage: receive_logs_direct.js [info] [warning] [error]"
        );
        process.exit(1);
    }

    const conn = await amqplib.connect("amqp://localhost");
    const ch = await conn.createChannel();

    let exchange = "direct_logs";

    await ch.assertExchange(exchange, "direct", {
        durable: true,
    });

    const q = await ch.assertQueue("", { exclusive: false, durable: true });

    args.forEach(function (severity) {
        ch.bindQueue(q.queue, exchange, severity);
    });

    ch.consume(
        q.queue,
        (msg) => {
            console.log(
                " [x] %s: '%s'",
                msg.fields.routingKey,
                msg.content.toString(),
                "sdfsdf"
            );
            ch.ack(msg);
        },
        {
            noAck: false,
        }
    );
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
};

receiveLogs();
```